# Cannot update kernel Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot, 16.04, grub2, kernel

**I'm trying to update the kernel on a VPS to 4.8 (or 4.8.X), but for whatever reason it's ignoring grub or something else is happening.**

`uname -a` produces `Linux vlanp 2.6.32-042stab120.6 #1 SMP Thu Oct 27 16:59:03 MSK 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

I followed the instructions on the following page: http://linuxg.net/install-kernel-4-8-on-ubuntu/ and running the command `dpkg --list | grep linux-image` lists it as installed:

```
ii  linux-image-4.6.0-040600-generic           4.6.0-040600.201606100558                     amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.6.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.6.0-040600-lowlatency        4.6.0-040600.201606100558                     amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.6.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.8.0-040800-generic           4.8.0-040800.201610022031                     amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.8.10-040810-generic          4.8.10-040810.201611210531                    amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.8.10 on 64 bit x86 SMP
```

I have attempted to reboot using `grub-reboot <number>` to try and get the kernel to boot at least once, but it reboots into 2.6 every time.

- There is no `/etc/default/grub` file
- There is no `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file

Here's the kernel list from `/boot/grub/menu.lst`:

```
title           Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS, kernel 4.8.0-040800-generic
root            (hd0,0)
kernel          /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-040800-generic root=/dev/hda1 ro quiet splash
initrd          /boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-040800-generic

title           Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS, kernel 4.8.0-040800-generic (recovery mode)
root            (hd0,0)
kernel          /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-040800-generic root=/dev/hda1 ro  single
initrd          /boot/initrd.img-4.8.0-040800-generic

title           Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS, kernel 4.6.0-040600-lowlatency
root            (hd0,0)
kernel          /boot/vmlinuz-4.6.0-040600-lowlatency root=/dev/hda1 ro quiet splash
initrd          /boot/initrd.img-4.6.0-040600-lowlatency

title           Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS, kernel 4.6.0-040600-lowlatency (recovery mode)
root            (hd0,0)
kernel          /boot/vmlinuz-4.6.0-040600-lowlatency root=/dev/hda1 ro  single
initrd          /boot/initrd.img-4.6.0-040600-lowlatency

title           Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS, kernel 4.6.0-040600-generic
root            (hd0,0)
kernel          /boot/vmlinuz-4.6.0-040600-generic root=/dev/hda1 ro quiet splash
initrd          /boot/initrd.img-4.6.0-040600-generic

title           Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS, kernel 4.6.0-040600-generic (recovery mode)
root            (hd0,0)
kernel          /boot/vmlinuz-4.6.0-040600-generic root=/dev/hda1 ro  single
initrd          /boot/initrd.img-4.6.0-040600-generic

title           Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS, memtest86+
root            (hd0,0)
kernel          /boot/memtest86+.bin
```

Comment: Since this is a VPS, the kernel is very probably set by the host, and you may or may not be able to change it. Ask them.